# SQL server 2014 installation : PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Whenever I try to install the instance features, this pops up in middle of the installation:

```
PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 2. Command line: C:\Windows\system32\unlodctr.exe /m:hkengperfctr.xml from directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the SQL Server 2014 installation when I am installing with default instance but when I changed my instance to named instance and provided some name other than default name installation completed without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced a similar error and situation for one of my customer, and the best possible solution is to remove the existing database engine and reinstall with a named instance.